# Placement new vs assignment in STL implementation

Tags: c++, new-operator, placement-new

I've been curiously inspecting STL's implementation and found this code in `experimental/optional`. Here's the code:

```
optional&
operator=(const optional& __opt)
{
    if (this->__engaged_ == __opt.__engaged_)
    {
        if (this->__engaged_)
            this->__val_ = __opt.__val_;
    }
    else
    {
        if (this->__engaged_)
            this->__val_.~value_type();
        else
            ::new(_VSTD::addressof(this->__val_)) value_type(__opt.__val_);
        this->__engaged_ = __opt.__engaged_;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

This is the copy assignment operator implementation for the `std::optional<T>` class. I believe that for effects of this discussion, it should also be important to make it clear what those variables are, so here's the classe's storage:

```
typedef _Tp value_type;
union
{
    char __null_state_;
    value_type __val_;
};
bool __engaged_ = false;
```

The first code excerpt shows assignments to `__val_` in two different ways, one using a simple assignment (`this->__val_ = __opt.__val_`) and the other using placement new (`::new(_VSTD::addressof(this->__val_)) value_type(__opt.__val_);`). What's the difference? Why use one or another, in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The storage inside an optional is not initialized by default. In the first case, the storage has already been constructed so it uses the object's copy assignment operator.

In the second case it needs to construct an object into the allocated storage because in that code path the lefthand side of the assignment has never had its storage constructed..

Comment: The important thing is that the assignment operator of `__val_` will assume the previous contents are valid. If the storage was reserved but never assigned, this prerequisite won't be met and you need to do something more complicated.

Comment: Yes @MarkRansom I got it know ;) I was missing the fact that the memory was not initialized yet, after realising that it becomes quite obvious :)

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less the only way to do this. When the rhs (`__opt`) is not 'engaged', it is needed to destruct `__val__`, and if it is engaged, while our member is not, we have to create an object there.

The first `if` deals with the case when both arguments are either 'engaged' or not 'engaged', and in this case either nothing should be done, or we can use simple assignment.